# When $E(X|Y)E(Y) = E(XY)$?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables. In what cases is the following statement true

> $E(X|Y)E(Y) = E(XY)$ a.s.,

other than the cases when $X$ and $Y$are independent, and when $E(X|Y)=EX$ a.s. ?

If $E(X|Y)E(Y) = E(XY)$ a.s.,, and it is not true that $E(X|Y)=EX$ a.s., then must

- $E(Y)=0$,
- $ E(XY)=0$?

Is each of  the following true:

- if $EY\neq 0$, then $E(X|Y)E(Y)=E(XY)$ a.s. and $E(X|Y)=EX$ a.s. are equivalent.
- $E(X|Y)E(Y)=E(XY)$ a.s., if and only if either $E(X|Y)=EX$ a.s., or $EY = E(XY)= 0$.

Is there an example where $E(X|Y)\neq EX$ a.s., and $EY = E(XY)= 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: if $E(X|Y)\neq E(X)$, then $E(X|Y)$ is a random variable function of Y. So the LHS is a r.v, but the RHS is a constant. They can't be equal to each other.

Comment: Edited, cheers!

Comment: Still, you would need $E(X|Y)$ to be a.s. equal to a constant, which you can't get unless $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @Feanor: "you would need E(X|Y) to be a.s. equal to a constant", must the constant be $EX$?

Comment: Yes. $E(E(X|Y)) = E(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Feanor! Are the folowing true: (1)if $EY\neq 0$, then $E(X|Y)E(Y)=E(XY)$ a.s. and $E(X|Y)=EX$ a.s. are equivalent? (2) if $EY= 0$, then $E(X|Y)E(Y)=E(XY)$ a.s. (3) $E(X|Y)E(Y)=E(XY)$ a.s. if and only if either $E(X|Y)=EX$ a.s., or $EY = 0$?

Comment: (1) is true, for a proof you might want to use $E(XY|Y) = E(X|Y)Y$ (and maybe you need some integrability assumptions); (2) is false, take $X=-Y$; (3) is false because (2) was false

Comment: @Feanor: Thanks! I updated the questions in my post. Could you also try to answer them?

Comment: @Feanor "which you can't get unless X and Y are independent" Not so.

Comment: @Did: Of course not so, thanks for noticing. I seem to have written some nonsense above.

Answer (score 3):

As Did rightly points out, $X$ and $Y$ need not be independent. However, in the equality $E(X|Y) E(Y) = E(XY)$ the right side is constant, and the left side is a random variable, so the only way to have equality is if either $E(X|Y) = \mathrm{const.}$ or $E(Y) = 0$.

If $E(Y) = 0$ then you need precisely $E(XY) = 0$. This does not tell you much about $X$; $X$ can be anything up to 'one degree of freedom'. More precisely, if you pick your favourite variable $X_0$ and you have any other variable $Z$ with $E(ZY) \neq 0$ (e.g. $Z=Y$ will work unless $Y$ is identically $0$, in which case any $X$ works anyway) then there will be a constant $c$ such that $X = X_0 + cZ$ satisfies $E(XY) = 0$. For instance, with the choice $X_0 = Y^2,\ Z = Y$ you can easily ensure that $E(Y) = 0$ and $E(XY) = 0$ but $E(X|Y) = X = Y^2 - cY$ is non-constant.

Note that $$E(XY) = E(E(XY|Y) = E(YE(X|Y)).$$ Thus, your original equation is equivalent to $E(YE(X|Y)) = E(Y)E(X|Y)$, which is equivalent to:
$$ (*) \qquad E((Y-E(Y))E(X|Y)) = 0. $$

If $E(X|Y) = \mathrm{const.}$ then $(*)$ clearly holds, because then $$E((Y-E(Y))E(X|Y)) = E(X|Y)E((Y-E(Y))) = 0. $$
The converse does not hold, and we will construct lots of counterexamples. To begin with, assume that $E(Y) = 0$ and that $X = f(Y)$ so that $(*) $ becomes $$E(Y f(Y)) = 0.$$ There a lot of ways to accomplish this, for example by ensuring that $Y$ has a symmetric distribution and that $f(y) = f(-y)$. As long as $f$ is not constant on the set of values taken by $Y$, $E(X|Y)$ isn't constant. (To be very concrete, take $Y$ uniform on $[-1,1]$ and $X = Y^2$).